# remove a block from an arraylist

Tags: java

I am writing a program that allows the user to enter information like the name and birth year for a person. This person can be an employee or student. Employees have the two things i mentioned in person above as well as salary and time employed in minutes (weird right?) while students have the two things in person as well as level, gpa and major. I need to have a method that can remove a whole person from the array list using a number(0-X) that represents the person in the list. For example, if i wanted to remove a person from my array list and i had already added 3 i could just enter "2" into my console to remove that entire person. My first thought was to copy and paste the add and just use it to remove but once i thought about it, the run would be extremely tedious. *Any constructive comments are greatly appreciated.*

```
       public class Employee extends Person {
    private int salary;
    private int employment;
        Employee(int A, String N) {
            super(A, N);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
    public void set_salary(int S){
        salary = S;
    }
    public void set_employment(int E){
        employment = E;
    }

    public int get_salary(){
        return salary;

    }

    public int get_employment(){
        return employment;


    }
    }

public class Person {
private String name;
private int birthyear;
Person(){
    name="?";
    birthyear=0;
}
Person (int A, String N) {
    name = N;
    birthyear = A;

}
public void set_birthyear(int A){
    birthyear = A;
}

public void set_name(String N){
    name = N;
}
public int get_birthyear(){
    return birthyear;
}
public String get_name(){
    return name;
}
}

public class Student extends Person {
private String level;
private double GPA;
private String major;
    Student(int A, String N) {
        super(A, N);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
    public void set_level(String L){
        level = L;
    }
    public void set_GPA(double G){
        GPA = G;
    }
    public void set_major(String M){
        major = M;
    }

    public String get_level(){
        return level;

    }

    public double get_GPA(){
        return GPA;

}
    public String get_major(){
        return major;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question, but if you are asking how to remove an element from an `ArrayList` by its index you can already do that. `ArrayList.remove(int index)`.

Comment: @Chris i guess my problem is i dont have them properly added through the add method. i added each data object when i need  to be grouping them into groups of 4 for the employee and 5 for the student. each one needs to be its own entry into the arraylist

Comment: Why not make a class to represent an employee and a student and add them to the `ArrayList` so all the properties of each person are grouped together?

Comment: Also, `ArrayList` is a generic type and you should probably make use of that rather than just allowing yourself to potentially throw any `Object` in to the list. Even if you don't use a class, I'd at least use an `ArrayList<String>` to hold your input.

Comment: @chris could you give me an example of how i could put the classes in to the 'ArrayList<String>' i have created the classes "Employee" and "Student" with constructors and accessors.

Comment: @chris i edited the post to show the classes that i have made

Answer (score 1):

Where to begin....

Things I see that need improvement.

1. Your class name.  You shouldn't have a class called PersonList.  That would tell me that it's a class that contains a list of Person or something, but why have a class named that at all...java has standard objects for that sort of thing -- like List for example.   So the first thing I would do is fix your class name to be something better. Maybe  MyClassToPracticeMessingAroundWithPersonLists for example ;)
2. Your methods are in the same boat that your class name was in.  You got to name them better.  I have no idea what they do based on the name.  removeAddedS --> what is that?  So try and come up with more constructive names.  Maybe something like:  removePerson(int indexOfPersonToRemoveFromList), another option might be createANewPersonBasedOnUserInput() etc..
3. Another thing I see from your latest edit is that methods should be camel-case instead of _ if you're adhering to java best practices.  So instead of `set_level and get_level` -- you would want to have `setLevel and getLevel`
4. Also avoid parameters such as `Student(int A, String N)` because just looking at that someone would have no idea what A or N is.  Looking at the code A is yearOfBirth and N is name -- so it would be better to name them like that.  So the constructor would look like:  `Student(int birthYear, String studentName)`

Here's a quickly thrown together example of what is clearer.  Let me know if it makes more sense to you then what you had so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PracticeAddingPeople {

private List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
private List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PracticeAddingPeople practiceAddingPeople = new PracticeAddingPeople();
    practiceAddingPeople.askTheUserWhatTheyWouldLikeToDo();
}

private void askTheUserWhatTheyWouldLikeToDo() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("1. Create a new Employee");
        System.out.println("2. Create a new Student");
        System.out.println("3. View the student list.");
        System.out.println("4. View the employee list.");
        System.out.println("5. Quit.");
        String whatTheUserWantsToDo = scanner.nextLine();
        if ("1".equals(whatTheUserWantsToDo)) {
            createANewEmployeeFromUserInput();
        } else if ("2".equals(whatTheUserWantsToDo)) {
            createANewStudentFromUserInput();
        } else if ("3".equals(whatTheUserWantsToDo)) {
            printTheListOfStudents();
        } else if ("4".equals(whatTheUserWantsToDo)) {
            printTheListOfEmployees();
        } else if ("5".equals(whatTheUserWantsToDo)) {
            System.out.println("Goodbye.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

}

private void createANewStudentFromUserInput() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.err.println("Enter the name of the employee: ");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the birth year of the employee: ");
    int birthyear = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    Student student = new Student(birthyear, name);
    studentList.add(student);
}

private void createANewEmployeeFromUserInput() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.err.println("Enter the name of the employee: ");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the birth year of the employee: ");
    int birthyear = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

    Employee employee = new Employee(birthyear, name);

    employeeList.add(employee);
}

private void removeAStudentFromTheList(int positionInList) {
    studentList.remove(positionInList);
}

private void printTheListOfStudents() {
    System.out.println("Students in the List:");
    System.out.println("=====================");
    for (Student student : studentList) {
        System.out.println(student.getName());
    }
}

private void printTheListOfEmployees() {
    System.out.println("Employees in the List:");
    System.out.println("=====================");
    for (Employee employee : employeeList) {
        System.out.println(employee.getName());
    }
}

class Employee extends Person {
    private int salary;
    private int employment;
    Employee(int birthYear, String name) {
        super(birthYear, name);
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public int getEmployment() {
        return employment;
    }

    public void setEmployment(int employment) {
        this.employment = employment;
    }
}

class Person {
    private String name;
    private int birthyear;
    Person(){
        name="?";
        birthyear=0;
    }
    Person (int birthYear, String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birthyear = birthYear;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getBirthyear() {
        return birthyear;
    }

    public void setBirthyear(int birthyear) {
        this.birthyear = birthyear;
    }
}

class Student extends Person {
    private String level;
    private double GPA;
    private String major;
    Student(int A, String N) {
        super(A, N);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(String level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public double getGPA() {
        return GPA;
    }

    public void setGPA(double GPA) {
        this.GPA = GPA;
    }

    public String getMajor() {
        return major;
    }

    public void setMajor(String major) {
        this.major = major;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i guess im confused on using the classes with my test class and the personlist class.

Comment: I updated the example to include your classes.  Did that help?

Comment: when i go to print the student list it does not give the birth i also need it to ask for the salary and employment time for employee and level gpa and major for student. would i just do something similar to what you had for the entry of the name and birth date

Comment: Yes exactly.  That's exactly what you would do.

Comment: i added this: `private void printTheListOfStudents() {
    System.out.println("Students in the List:");
    System.out.println("=====================");
    for (Student student : studentList) {
        System.out.println(student.getName());
        System.out.println(student.getBirthyear());
        System.out.println(student.getLevel());
        System.out.println(student.getGPA());
        System.out.println(student.getMajor());
    }
}`

Comment: if i wanted to add a salary to the `createANewEmployeeFromUserInput() {` how would i go about doing that

Comment: i figured that out i am now getting an error when i try to remove